# Patchman Error during install ModuleNot Found Error: 'importlib.metadata' --python3-patchman

Tags: python, linux

I have attached the image of the error [dpkg error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrsRX.png)

I'm not really a developer so I am not sure how to troubleshoot something like this really?  what direction should I be going?

I've looked around for ways to install any missing dependencies but now its unable to connect to "patchman server"  which I don't believe has even been defined yet with a host/ip

> dpkg: error processing package python3-patchman (--configure):
> installed python3-patchman package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> python3-patchman
> Sending report to patchman server ...
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.